# How to use std::find for a class vector?

Tags: c++, vector

```
class g {
public:
    int x, y, z;
};
vector<g>f;
int main() {
    g obj1 = { 1,2,3 };
    f.push_back(obj1);
    auto it = find(f.begin(), f.end(), 2);
    f.erase(it);
}
```

This code gives me a C2678 error: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'g' .

Comment: you're comparing `g` to `int`, but `g` is not an `int`.

Comment: Do you mean I have to compare it to {x,y,z}?

Comment: you have to compare it to something that `g` can be compared with. this can be achieved by implementing `operator ==`. this way you can tell how `g` is compared to `XXX`. may `XXX` is `g`, `int` or anything else

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `==` operator for your class:

```
class g {
public:
    int x, y, z;

    bool operator==(const g& o) const {
        return x == o.x && y == o.y && z == o.z;
    }
};
```

Use correct type as the parameter:

```
auto it = std::find(f.begin(), f.end(), g{1, 2, 3});
```

Comment: you forgot `noexcept`

Comment: Am I overloading the '==' operator here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda and the standard algorithm `std::find_if`.

If I have correctly understood your code then you need something like

```
int  x = 2;
auto it = find_if( f.begin(), 
                   f.end(), 
                   [x]( const g &item ) 
                   { 
                       return item.x == x || item.y == x || item.z == x;
                   } );
```

Comment: What if x,y,z are of different type? Would it then be possible to get the position of the element based on just one of those variables?

Comment: @JXkcd At first you should describe what you are trying to do. As for your question then you can declare a tuple instead of separate data members within the class.

Comment: @JXkcd  Another approach is to define several function objects for each data member of the class used in the algorithm.

Comment: @JXkcd You can replace `item.x == x || item.y == x || item.z == x;` with anything you want to tell it what to look for.